# Tracking of URL's visited. Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am learning javascript and thought of making a chrome extension that keeps record of every URL that is visited by user. Each visited URL will be stored only once.

This is my background.js

```
var sites = [];

function startAction()
{
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
        var tablink = tab.url;
        var len = sites.length();
        for(var i = 0;i < len; i++)
        {
          if(sites[i] == tablink)
          {
            console.log("Already in list");
          }
        }
        if(i == len)
        {
          sites[i] = tablink;
          console.log("Newly added");
        }
    });
    print();
}

function print()
{
    var len = sites.length();
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
            console.log(sites[i]);
    }
}

startAction();
```

But on running this error is shown in Console

`Error in response to tabs.getSelected: TypeError: number is not a function
    at startAction`

What does this mean? Am I using a correct approach? How to overcome this error?

**Edit:**

As suggested by RobW, I changed position of `print()` into callback function and edited `sites.length()` to `sites.length`. Error is gone now. But this code doesn't print URLs visited in console. How to do that?

Comment: What is `t2` in `var x = tablink.substring(0,t2);`?

Comment: @VivekPradhan That's not there.. edited.

Comment: Can't you understand the error message? It sayd that number is not a function... and indeed, `sites.length` is a numeric property, not a function. Omit the braces. Beside that, but `print();` in the callback function of `chrome.tabs.getSelected`. Otherwise it won't print any results.

Comment: @RobW Please make that into an answer.

Comment: @RobW Thanks for the reply. Error is gone. But the output is not getting updated every time I open some website. Is my approach correct for what I wanted to do?

Comment: You need to hook onto some event. Try `webNavigation` API or events in `tabs` API.